# Integrated Image Picker like Facebook

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there an integrated image picker available like the one in Facebook or twitter app. All photos are displayed in cells and the camera is shown as first item. Look at the attached image for what I am looking for.

[image]

Comment: This isn't google. Do some research first (http://google.com), then come here if you have questions on what you've learned or what you've done

Comment: I searched google. I did not find any answer. I have an idea how to implement it. I can browse through asset library and fill cells of a collection view. In the cellForItemAtIndexPath for section 0 I can return the camera button. I wanted to ask if there is an ready solution which I can use to save some coding time.

Comment: You may want to try browsing sites like Github or [CocoaControls](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not find any solution which matched my need. So I ended up writing one. Here is a link on github if any one wants to use the control.

[Custom Image Picker](https://github.com/cspnanda/CustomImagePicker)